# About MySQL Subsum

Tags: mysql, subtotal

I am having trouble getting MySQL subtotals.

source data

url count

```
/test/a/1/temp.txt 10
/test/a/2/temp.txt 10
/test/a/3/temp.txt 10
/test/b/1/temp.txt 10
/test/1/temp.txt 10
/test/1/temp2.txt 10
/test/1/temp3.txt 10
```

result

url count level

```
/test    70    1
/test/a    30    2
/test/a/1    10    3
/test/a/1/temp.txt    10    4
/test/a/2    10    3
/test/a/2/temp.txt    10    4
/test/a/3    10    3
/test/a/3/temp.txt    10    4
/test/b    40    2
/test/b/1    10    3
/test/b/1/temp.txt    10    4
/test/1    30    2
/test/1/temp.txt    10    3
/test/1/temp2.txt    10    3
/test/1/temp3.txt    10    3
```

I want to know how.

Thanks
Best Regards.

Comment: Please provide the DDL and query being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your particular data, you can do:

```
select url, sum(count(*)
from ((select substring_index(url, '/', 2) as url, count
       from source
      ) union all
      (select substring_index(url, '/', 3) as url, count
       from source
      ) union all
      (select substring_index(url, '/', 4) as url, count
       from source
      ) union all
      (select substring_index(url, '/', 5) as url, count
       from source
      ) 
     ) s
group by url
order by url;
```